# Custom script in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just started playing with Meteor and  i was testing few things. Based on the [Meteor Guide](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Style-Guide)  i was testing below code to understand the best way to write packages but i never been successful. What is wrong with the following code and what is good way (if not all but atleast few good ways) to write the packages for Meteor app which can be placed in lib folder.

### /lib/exports.js

```
if (org === void 0){
    var org = {}
}
if(bjse === void 0){
    var bjse = {};
    if(typeof exports != "undefined"){
        bjse = exports;
    }
    bjse.api = {};
}
```

### /lib/file1.js

// mypackage.js

```
bjse.api.Whirlygig = function (name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;  // name of the remote weasel
  self.values = {};  // remote key name -> 0-indexed value

};

_.extend(Whirlygig.prototype, {
  // Take a key/value pair from the remote Weasel and save it locally.
  addValue: function (x) {
    // Weasels use 1-indexed arrays. Subtract 1 to convert to 0-indexed.
    self.values[x.key] = x.value - 1;
  },

  // Return a list of stored values in a format suitable for sending to
  // a Weasel.
  serialize: function () {
    return _.map(self.values, function (v, k) {
      var newVal = mungeValue(v, false /* foldValue */);
      // Weasels use 1-indexed arrays. Add 1 to convert back to 1-indexed.
      newVal = newVal + 1;
      return {key: k, value: newVal};
    });
  }
});
```

### /server/methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    createConnections: function(){
  ....
 var serializeObj = bjse.api.Whirlygig.serialize(..);
```

But i get Whirlygig not defined.

### Update

I want to use bjse as namespace but it always appears as not defined in other files.

Comment: Make it global variable and in package.js make it run on server, you can find more info [here](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing)

Comment: how to make it global variable?

Comment: Remove `var` from Whirlywig. If you want to create package you can use mine simple lib to check how I've done it, it's really simple so you should read it with no problem - [link](https://github.com/Sindis/easy-check)

Comment: I'm not going to do Atmosphere package, just small custom script that i'm trying to run from methods.js. So i'm trying to exports as  below if (bjse == void 0) {
     bjse = {};
    if (typeof exports != "undefined") {
        bjse = exports;
    }
    bjse.api = {};
} But in the methods i still see bjse is not defined even after removing var

Answer (score 0):

In `exports` you want:

```
if (typeof(org) === 'undefined'){
    var org = {}
}
if(typeof(bjse) === 'undefined'){
    var bjse = {};
    if(typeof exports != "undefined"){
        bjse = exports;
    }
    bjse.api = {};
}
```

Comment: No i don't have var before Whirlygig anymore and even i define the namespace first, i still get Whirlygig as not defined.

Comment: you can't compare an undefined variable with anything (if (org ===void 0)), you have to compare its *type*

Comment: I changed the exports with what you suggested but i still have issue

Comment: Set the debugger to stop on file1.js and step through it to see where it's breaking.

Comment: exports or module.exports are undefined when exports.js file is loaded. So after removing  
the following piece 


    if(typeof exports != "undefined"){
        bjse = exports;
    } and also removing var before bjse, it worked. So is there a way i can do it using exports?

Comment: That's more of a node question, dk. You don't really need them to solve your problem. Plus if this is meant to be server-side only you should put your files in /server instead of /lib because exports won't be on the client.